# How to use the rollback command in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rollback

I am trying to use rollback command in sql but it is not working.

```
USE MFF

BEGIN TRANSACTION 
BEGIN TRY

    INSERT INTO dbo.people 
    VALES ('Nick', 1)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    /* Ocurrió un error, deshacemos los cambios*/ 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    PRINT 'An error has occurred!'
END CATCH
```

I misspelled the word "vales" on purpose so that it goes through the catch part, but it comes out earlier. Do I have to enable something in the database?

My need is to rollback a larger script and I want to see how it works in case of an error.

Comment: This error is a syntax error, so the code won't even start to be run because SQL can't understand it. It's a compile-time error. Try/catch is for trapping unexpected runtime errors.

Comment: I would advise you not to bother with `TRY/CATCH`: if there is an error then you will see the message anyway. Just put `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` at the top, and all errors will cause an immediate rollback

Comment: The easiest way to test the `ROLLBACK` is to add the line `PRINT 1/0` after your `INSERT`. This is only for testing, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a try/catch on a syntax error. That won't work because your query won't even parse correctly.

You need to do the try/catch on a valid query. Here is an example of using your logic with a slightly different `people` table:

```
create table #people (firstname varchar(100), ID INT PRIMARY KEY)
GO

--run this twice to see it succeed the first time, and throw your print error on the 2nd run.
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
BEGIN TRY

    insert into #people 
    values 
    ('Nick',1)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH


    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    PRINT 'An error has occurred!'

END CATCH
```